# MySQL 5.5 add foreign key fails with errors [HY000][150] and [HY000][1005]

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, dml

I have tried adding a foreign key like this...

```
ALTER TABLE OrderLineItem
ADD CONSTRAINT
        FK_OrderLineItem_ShippingType_name FOREIGN KEY
(shippingType)
REFERENCES ShippingType(name);
```

Or like this in Mysql 5.5...

```
alter table OrderLineItem add foreign key 
FK_OrderLineItem_ShippingType (shippingType) references ShippingType(name);
```

Every time I see the following error.

> [2011-11-18 15:07:04] [HY000][150] Create table
>   'realtorprint_dev_dev/#sql-7d0_80' with foreign key constraint failed.
>   There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns
>   appear as the first columns.
>
> [2011-11-18 15:07:04] [HY000][1005] Can't create table
>   'realtorprint_dev_dev.#sql-7d0_80' (errno: 150)

Both OrderLineItem.shippingType and ShippingType.name have a type of varchar(50) not null.  ShippingType.name is the primaryKey of ShippingType.

Here is the result of show create table on ShippingType as well as OrderLineItem...

```
CREATE TABLE `shippingtype` (
  `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `orderlineitem` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `lineNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantityMultiplier` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unitPrice` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `productDefinition_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `mlsId` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `printProviderUnitCost` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `shippingType` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zipPostal` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `stateProvince` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_OrderLineItem_productDefinition_id` (`productDefinition_id`),
  KEY `idx_OrderLineItem_order_id` (`order_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_OrderLineItem_order_id` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `userorder` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_OrderLineItem_productDefinition_id` FOREIGN KEY (`productDefinition_id`) REFERENCES `productdefinition` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10029 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I missed the bit about it being the primary key. Let me check

Comment: Works for me - are the columns exactly the same type in both tables? I've seen this when there is a slight type mismatch (collation etc)

Comment: Wow, looks like you were right.

Comment: Cool - I updated my answer to include - I spent a few hours looking at this one once in mysql :-) which is why I remember.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is possible is that Mysql gives this bad error when the column types do not match exactly - check collation / size etc.

Comment: It's true! Dammint  "unsigned" in "create table" statement! Thank you!

Comment: Don't think guys that the error tells nothing about the problem, I consider this a bad programming style !

Comment: This solved it for me -- interesting that this same issue doesn't throw an error in MariaDB v10

Answer (score 10):

`orderLineItem.shippingType` has character set `utf8`, but `ShippingType.name` has character set `latin1`. These are not compatible for the purposes of foreign key references.

Comment: we got same error with different column collation. you can check reference table column collation with SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tableName;

Answer (score -2):

Data type mismatches or PK not declared properly on referenced based tables.